# Add small "buffer" to flex wrap in css

Tags: javascript, css, sass, flexbox

Im creating a multi-select-field in Vue and SCSS. A cross symbol is being displayed on each
element when hovered, inside a parent flex wrap element. So naturally when the child elements change in size they wrap. Therefore I want to create a small "buffer" in the wrap parent element so that they are wrapped before the cross is taking up space. I've tried to use a buffer padding on the flex wrap div that gets removed on hover, but it affects all rows therefore it did not work?

Any way to achieve this without the children inside the flex wrap exactly taking up space?

Here is how it looks now:
[image]

I try to avoid direct DOM manipulation because I'm using a web framework. So a non pure css or Vue solution would also work great!

I have no idea of how to tackle this problem so I have no code to show, but maybe grid would work better?

Here is the code that I currently have:

```html
<Flex 
    v-for="option in selectedOptions.slice(0, maxSelectedOptions)"
    @click="() => removeSelectedOption(option)"
    class="selected-option" 
    gap="0.2rem" 
    align="center" 
    justify="center"
>
    <img 
        class="icon" 
        :src="option.img" 
        :alt="option.label"
        loading="lazy"
    >
    <p>{{ option.label }}</p>
    <img class="cross contrast-filter" src="/cross.svg">
</Flex>
```

```css
flex-wrap: wrap;
overflow: auto;
```